# How can I serve static files with 404 redirection by PM2?

Tags: pm2

I already know that there is a simple command to serve static folder by PM2:

```
pm2 serve <path> <port>
```

But how can I add 404 redirection to it? e.g. redirect to `404.html` while that happends. Can't find that on Google & PM2 doc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, `pm2` displays **404.html** from the serving directory if it can't map a request to any static file of that directory. For example, assume that your static file directory name is **foo**, which contains three images - `1.jpg`, `2.jpg`, `3.jpg`. You are serving those files using:

```
pm2 serve <path_of_foo> 8080
```

Now, if the server receives any request like `http://localhost:8080/bar.jpg`, `pm2` will look for a file named `404.html` on **foo** directory and display its contents, as `bar.jpg` does not exist. If it doesn't find any, it show a simple text message **404 Not Found**. There is no options to make it configurable (CLI or JSON), as per my knowledge.

However, if you make this file path configurable, you can take a look at [here](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/blob/master/lib/API/Serve.js#L225) and customize the source according to your need.